How to avoid "Cannot access a disposed object" MemoryStream errors in async lambda functions
I have an issue that I can solve by running my code synchronously and it works great but to reduce wait time for my users I need to run async for this method as I have a few other tasks that need to run as well but I omitted for testing purposes but use the same procedures. I get an error in my Azure download method (DriveItemDownloadAsync) I created as shown:

System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisitionAspnetCoreHost.GetEffectiveAuthenticationScheme(String authenticationScheme)
at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisitionAspnetCoreHost.GetOptions(String authenticationScheme, String& effectiveAuthenticationScheme)
at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForUserAsync(IEnumerable1 scopes, String authenticationScheme, String tenantId, String userFlow, ClaimsPrincipal user, TokenAcquisitionOptions tokenAcquisitionOptions)   at Microsoft.Identity.Web.DefaultAuthorizationHeaderProvider.CreateAuthorizationHeaderForUserAsync(IEnumerable1 scopes, AuthorizationHeaderProviderOptions downstreamApiOptions, ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisitionAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
at Microsoft.Graph.AuthenticationHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)}

The code I am using in my controller is as follows. If I remove the Task and make this run synchronously no error happens.
Task ReportTask = new Task(async () => {
                    var reportPathOneDrive = "path.docx";
                    var reportPathBox = "path.docx";

                    var FileInfo = await oneDrive.DriveItemInfoAsync(SharedDriveID, reportPathOneDrive, "path");

                    var memoryStream = await oneDrive.DriveItemDownloadAsync(SharedDriveID, reportPathOneDrive, "path");

                    MemoryStream memoryStreamBox = new MemoryStream();
                    memoryStream.CopyTo(memoryStreamBox);
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    memoryStreamBox.Position = 0;

                    //add to email
                    var attachment = new ARMS.Models.FileAttachment
                    {
                        FileName = FileInfo.Name.ToString(),
                        ContentType = FileInfo.File.MimeType.ToString(),
                        ContentBytes = memoryStream.ToArray()
                    };

                    attachments.Add(attachment);

                    var uploadBox = await boxDrive.UploadFileAsync(BoxARMSFolderID, memoryStreamBox, reportPathBox);
                });

                ReportTask.Start();
                List<Task> documentTasks = new List<Task> { ReportTask };

                await Task.WhenAll(documentTasks);

The error will appear in this function here:
public async Task<MemoryStream> DriveItemDownloadAsync(string DriveID, string PathOrDriveItemID, string SearchType)
{
    var tries = 0;
    var maxRetries = 1;

    Stream response = null;
    var MemoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    while (tries <= maxRetries)
    {
        tries++;

        try
        {
            if (SearchType == "path")
            {
                response = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Drives[DriveID].Root
                                .ItemWithPath(PathOrDriveItemID)
                                .Content
                                .Request()
                                .GetAsync();
            }
            else if (SearchType == "id")
            {
                response = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Drives[DriveID]
                                .Items[PathOrDriveItemID]
                                .Content
                                .Request()
                                .GetAsync();
            }

            response.CopyTo(MemoryStream);
            MemoryStream.Position = 0;

            tries = maxRetries + 1;
        }
        catch (ServiceException svcex) when (svcex.Message.Contains("Continuous access evaluation resulted in claims challenge"))
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{svcex}");
                string claimChallenge = WwwAuthenticateParameters.GetClaimChallengeFromResponseHeaders(svcex.ResponseHeaders);
                _consentHandler.ChallengeUser(initialScopes, claimChallenge);
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                _consentHandler.HandleException(ex2);
            }
        }
    }

    return MemoryStream;
}

The response line where it actually goes to use MS Graph is what draws the error. I know I need to be careful with memory streams in async but I thought I was using them correctly in this sense with the lambda function. In fact this is the first time I have used lambda in a New Task() object so I am thinking that could be an issue?

The exception has nothing todo with the code you provided in your question. Looks to me like your app is setting up a DI container, the controller you are referring to uses DI to inject services into the controller. At that point in time, the DI container is already disposed though <- that's what the exception is referring to at least.

Why would a DI container dispose of there is an await task.whenall set so the parent controller doesn’t complete without the sub tasks completing.

Where and how do you create the _graphServiceClient object?

I believe in my base controller which is implemented by all my controllers I have a dependency injection created there for _graphserviceclient and I think if I remember correctly it’s a transient in program.cs

Do I need to use dependency injection in the lambda function somehow to ensure a new service is registered for each task/thread?

Hi Qiuzman, could you try to use Task.Run(async () => { , instead of  new Task(async () => { ? Please let me know the test result.

@Qiuzman the exception comes from DI, that's all I know. Your code does not show where the DI container is actually created. I also don't know enough about lamda functions and how that framework manages your apps lifetime. If all resources automatically dispose after the "request" is over, then you'd have to make sure to await any tasks which still run in the background, otherwise those will just continue running.

@jason I have been out of work part few days but I did manage to put each task as it’s own async function and call the tasks similar to here and it works. It’s almost like new Task with the lambda does not maintain the dependency injection and should be treated as it’s own function and the dependency injection should occur inside the lambda function. Atleast that’s my guess. I will try task.run() as a test though next week when I’m back.
